# Examples for getx redirect

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I am using getx cli to creat the skeleton project, getx create project.

I am trying to find how we can use getx redirect to redirect the users to either home page or login page based on the authentication state. Thanks for your help.

https://github.com/jonataslaw/getx/#redirect

Comment: What have you tried so far? Check "[What can I ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)" here to know on-topic questions.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem. Every GetPage has a middleware prop that takes in a list of middlewares you can create a class that extends the GetMiddleware and overrride the redirect there.
For example:

```
class AuthMiddleware extends GetMiddleware { 
   @override redirect() { 
      if(check){ 
         return RouteSettings(route: '/dashboard') } return null; 
      }  
   }
}
```

I hope it helps